# After importing items are not displaying

Tags: import, bulk-import

I found an issue after importing the items. New items cant't be displayed on the list in frontend but they are added to the admin dashboard. Manually updated I can see them on the list.

CMS: Wordpress Plugins I use: Essential Real Estate, WP All Import.

The question: how can I see them added right after importing ? what can make the items not displaying ?

Thank you

Comment: You could check in the database to see what's different about the posts that aren't displaying. You will likely need to contact WP All Import for support in troubleshooting once you find out what's different.

Comment: I did it and found that it's only the column "guid" that was different. I changed it but the items didn't displayed.

Comment: guid is just an autogenerated unique identifier. It's okay if that is different; it's really not used for anything other than ensuring each post has a unique key. Definitely sounds like a question for WP All Import support. Or you might want to try using a different theme on a staging site, importing, and seeing if you have the same issue when another theme is active - that would indicate you need to contact theme support.

Comment: I found that it could be a code of the plugin I use. There is the code of the search filter 1 I have a problem with, but using another search filter I can get the new items. I've been spending many hours but didn't found the part of code that can provoke the issue.

Comment: What I see that my new imported posts is not in the post type 'property' but when I update manually the post it appears.